# Oozie job.properties

Tags: jobs, oozie

I'm almost done with reproducing [CDH twitter example](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example), and at the moment it fails at this point:

```
 sudo oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config ~/oozie/oozie-workflows
  /job.properties -run
```

with

> Error: HTTP error code: 500 : Internal Server Error

The `job.properties` file says

```
nameNode=hdfs://hadoop1:8020
jobTracker=hadoop1:8021
workflowRoot=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/oozie-workflows
```

and oozie logs say

```
ERROR V1JobsServlet:536 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] URL[POST     
http://localhost:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start] error,         
java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop1
```

I think the nameNode line just has to be edited, but I can't see how exactly.
It's probably quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the place of Hadoop1 against jobtracker and namenode properties,please give ipadress .

it is unable to resolve hadoop1.

Comment: I'm running the whole setup in a VM, so I thought that hadoop1 would automagically be resolved to localhost. But your advice is probably right.

Comment: Techincally, I replaced `hadoop1` with `localhost.localdomain`, but it still worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cluster, the nameNode could set to the cluster name.
like:

```
hdfs://[CLUSTERNAME]
```